# How to develop masterpage, details page structure in angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have below code in app.component.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1> 
</div>
<div>
<p-menu [model]="items"></p-menu>
</div>
```

app.component.ts file has below code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MenuModule} from 'primeng/menu';
import {MenuItem} from 'primeng/api';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Demo';

  items: MenuItem[];

  ngOnInit() {
      this.items = [
          {label: 'New', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-plus'},
          {label: 'Open', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-download'},
          {label: 'Undo', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-refresh',url: 'http://www.google.com'}
      ];
  }

}
```

Clicking on Undo, completely redirecting to google website. I want to open google website within my application itself.

[image]

Scenario:

Menu exists in Masterpage. When the user clicks on any menu link in the master page, data should get displayed in the details page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open any website in your application, you need to use an `<iframe>`

```
<iframe 
    width="300"
    height="200"
    [src]="yourLink">
</iframe>
```